# Выборка данных C# EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Сайт, каждый юзер может создать список сериалов которые он смотрит и отмечать серии которые он посмотрел. Из бд(на code first) нужно выбрать и вывести в представлении для каждого юзера список серий которые он еще не смотрел. Регу сделал, в контроллере нахожу данного авторизованного юзера и возвращаю его в представление, там я уже могу на рейзоре выводить его список сериалов и тд, но не могу сделать вывод конкретно этого и возможно, я сделал кривую модель бд. Дайте совет как собственно переделать бд\вывести список не просмотренных серий юзера[image: моя бд]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Я бы реализовал модель примерно так:

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Episode> WatchedEpisodes { get; set; } = new List<Episode>();
}

public class Serial
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Season> Seasons { get; set; } = new List<Season>();
}

public class Season
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Episode> Episodes { get; set; } = new List<Episode>();
    public virtual Serial Serial { get; set; }
}

public class Episode
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Season Season { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда, пусть у нас имеется произвольный `User u` и некоторый сериал `Serial s`, выбираем все непросмотренные эпизоды заданного сериала указанным юзером:

```
var unwatchedEpisodes = s.Seasons
                         .SelectMany(season => season.Episodes)
                         .Where(episode => !u.WatchedEpisodes.Contains(episode))
                         .ToList();
```

**UPD.** Обратите внимание на добавленный `.ToList()` в конце - он "материализует" запрос и все последующие операции будут выполняться с локальной коллекцией без запросов в БД.

Построение и обход дерева будет выглядеть вот так:

```
var tree = unwatchedEpisodes.GroupBy(episode => episode.Season)
                            .GroupBy(group => group.Key.Serial)
                            .ToList();
foreach (var serialGroup in tree)
    foreach (var seasonGroup in serialGroup)
        foreach (var episode in seasonGroup)
            Console.WriteLine($"Сериал: {serialGroup.Key.Name} | Сезон: {seasonGroup.Key.Name} | Эпизод: {episode.Name}");
```

**UPD.** Я не проверял на "живой" базе поэтому не уверен, но, скорее всего, чтобы результат запроса к БД включал в себя информацию о сезонах и сериалах нужно будет воспользоваться методом `.Include()`, примерно так:

```
var unwatchedEpisodes = s.Seasons
                         .SelectMany(season => season.Episodes)
                         .Where(episode => !u.WatchedEpisodes.Contains(episode))
                         .Include(episode => episode.Season)
                         .Include(episode => episode.Season.Serial)
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: А как у нас будет вообще отмечаться то что уже просмотрено в бд? Что-то не совсем понял этот момент

Comment: @Devoli, `User.WatchedEpisodes` - список просмотренных эпизодов данным юзером

Comment: Значит у нас серии будут добавляться в коллекцию когда мы посмотрели серию и например как у меня была переменная bool Watched по сути совсем не нужна?

Comment: @Devoli, верно, не нужна.

Comment: @Devoli, вообще эта промежуточная таблица view не нужна. В моем примере между Users и Episodes хоть и есть связь многие ко многим, но она останется за кадром на совести EF

Comment: А вот смотрите, ваш запрос возвращает просто все серии же, а мне, например, нужно в представление вывести все иерархически, вроде имя сериала -> номер сезона -> серии, мне в итоге же все равно придется все перебирать в самой вьюшке и не как иначе, да?

Comment: @Devoli, каждая серия "знает" к какому сезону она принадлежит, а сезон, в свою очередь, знает к какому сериалу он принадлежит. Смотрите в обновленном ответе как можно используя это построить и обойти дерево.